# psycopg2: Copy vs Execute-Fetch

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm new with `psycopg2` and I do have a question (which I cannot really find a respond in the Internet): Do we have any difference (for exemaple in the aspect of performance) between using `copy_xxx()` method and combo `execute() + fetchxxx()` method when we try to write the result of query into a CSV file?

```
...
query_str = "SELECT * FROM mytable"
cursor.execute(query_str)
with open("my_file.csv", "w+") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    while True:
        rows = cursor.fetchmany()
        if not rows:
           break
        writer.writerows(rows)
```

vs

```
...
query_str = "SELECT * FROM mytable"
output_query = f"COPY {query_str} TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER"
with open("my_file.csv", "w+") as file:
   cursor.copy_expert(output_query, file)
```

And if I try to do a very complex query (my assumption is that we cannot simplify this query anymore for ex) with `psycopg2`, which method should I use? Or do you guys have any advice, please?

Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

`COPY` is faster, but if query execution time is dominant or the file is small, it won't matter much.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show us how the cursor was declared.  If it is an anonymous cursor, then execute/fetch will read all query data into memory upfront, leading to out of memory conditions for very large queries.  If it is a named cursor, then you will individually request every row from the server, leading to horrible performance (which can be overcome by specifying a count argument to `fetchmany`, as the default is bizarrely set to 1)